# Grails spock unit testing query

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking, spock

I'm using grails 2.3.7  ..  in a Spock unit test i'm mocking a findWhere method   ..

```
  DocumentHeader.metaClass.static.findWhere = {DocumentType type, String workStation, Boolean complete ->
            println "Running mock findWhere .. "
            new DefaultDocument()
        }
```

which i'm using to mock a method call in a service  ..

```
def returnDocument =  DocumentHeader.findWhere(documentType:DocumentType.DEFAULT_TYPE,
                        workStation: requirement.workstation,
                        complete: false)
```

The parameter types are correct but when invoke the test I get

```
Cannot query [com.sample.DocumentHeader] on non-existent property: workStation org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Cannot query [com.vantec.DocumentHeader] on non-existent property: workStation
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.simple.query.SimpleMapQuery
```

so it appears to be invoking the real method - not the mock  ..  Anyone any ideas ? Don't recall mocking a findWhere query before so anyone know of any problems ?  TIA ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this code, you are mocking (or rather adding) method

```
DocumentHeader findWhere(DocumentType dt, String w, Boolean c)
```

But in you service you are calling

```
DocumentHeader findWhere(Map props)
```

Try changing your metaClass to:

```
DocumentHeader.metaClass.static.findWhere = {Map props ->
    println "Running mock findWhere .. "
    new DefaultDocument()
}
```